# Fluid floating divs on same line in CSS

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have an image, with text directly below it. I wrap it up in a `div` and center the contents inside.

Now let's say I have 20 of these, all with the same sized image (i.e. 65px) but different amounts of text (text can wrap).

What I want to achieve with this is the following:

I would like to display as many as possible on the same line with 10px of left/right margin around each one. Also, they will always center and equally fill the width of the browser window.

Ideally, if the browser width was super small, it would just display one on each line.

Anyone have a CSS solution for this type of scenario?

It is strictly for mobile... no need to worry about I.E.

Thanks a lot!

**Update**

Heres some basic code I am working with.. as you can see it does the job if I hardcode 4 per line (width 25% each):

HTML:

```
<div class="m-parent-navigation-container">
    <div class="m-icon-navigation-container">
        <a class="m-icon-navigation-link"><img><br></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.m-parent-navigation-container
    {
    margin: 0 10px;
    color: rgb(26, 46, 120);
    font-size: 0.9em;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.m-icon-navigation-container
    {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    }

.m-icon-navigation-link
    {
    display: block;
    font-family: OpenSansBold;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: What's your problem? Have you tried yet? Can we see your code? Or do you just want us to do it for you?

Comment: Can you provide at least some code to start with? It's not the greatest to ask people to just do the work for you. Give us a starting point and we can help.

Comment: Sounds like `display: flex` might work.

Comment: flex isn't fully supported yet though...might be some problems, but definitely a great idea

Comment: Updated post with some preliminary sample code. The fluidity is the difficult part for me right now. @Whymarrh I will take a look at this... I remember reading about it a few weeks back but I think even on mobile it is lacking in implementation, particularly with current Status Quo version of Android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/3QSVg/

The important parts are the `display: inline-block;` and `text-align: center;`

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're after, but it's a start.

EDIT:

Here is an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/j78Qw/1/

It's a bit closer to what you want, I think. But it still has some issues.

Comment: Yes, indeed this a great start - thank you. Is it possible to make the divs distribute across the width of the browser? Think of the 10px margin between them a minimum margin... that's what I'm after.

Comment: mushroom, this looks like a clean way to approach my problem in a pure css manner. the :after selector was something I wasn't too familiar with. Thanks for spending time on this. I will mark this as solved

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex-box for this. The browser support is still lacking, but if you develop mainly for the webkit rendering engine, i.e. iOS, Android, Chrome on Windows, you can use it.

Look at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fHklC

Comment: This is a great demo and I was actually attempting to integrate this solution you gave, however, having to support Android 2.3+ puts me at a huge disadvantage, due to partial support of old and new syntax. The main deal breaker was no support for multi-line flexboxes on android 2.3. I will upvote this because I feel it's of great value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pure CSS solution, I believe.

First, you should `float: left` the image boxes. Using JS you can get width of the outer container, and divide it by the width of the image box. This will give you a number, how many image boxes can fit. Now you can calculate maximum possible size of the box to fill the whole width of the container. This will allow you to align images to the center.

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li><img src="…" /></li>
    <li><img src="…" /></li>
    …
</ul>

var list = $('#gallery');
var items = list.find('li');

var imageWidth = items.width('auto').outerWidth(true);
var nrOfItemsPerRow = Math.min(Math.floor(list.innerWidth() / imageWidth), items.length);
items.css('width', Math.floor(100 / nrOfItemsPerRow) + '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` is your friend here.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vmu9R/1/

There are a couple of caveats with `inline-block` in that it is not supported well in I.E.7 and earlier but there are work-arounds.

This article covers the work-arounds and is generally a good article on inline-block

not that you are concerned by I.E.7 but for those who maybe, conditionally include the following

```
/* For IE 7 */
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to line up `div`s (with whatever content), have the be fluid width, and have them wrap as needed once there isn't enough room on the page?

[Flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/) might be able to accomplish this. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUKz7/).

Some good resources for Flexbox things:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes
- http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/
- http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

[Can you use it?](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)